# Return a value if no rows selected are found Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's my simple query. If I query a record that doesn't exist then I will get nothing returned.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN table1.column1= @column1  THEN 'XX' 
ELSE 'YY' END from table1 where table1.column2=@column2
```

It returns no rows selected.

I tried `ISNULL()` .But not rectified

I need to return 'YY'

Could anyone helpme out..!!
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it.

Comment: Are there any records in `SELECT * from table1 where table1.column2=@column2` ?

Comment: based on the input( @column2 ) records are present

Comment: This is not an Oracle query. Which database are you using? Add proper tags

Comment: Oracle10g itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you have posted has @ symbol, which is not the default substitution character for variables in Oracle as in SQL-Server, unless you have used something like

`SET DEFINE @`  and put quotes while passing string literals.Not sure if you are using it that way.

I would suggest you to use a bind variable which is prefixed by a colon  `:`

Regarding your question

> I need to return 'YY'

for `no rows selected`, you could put your case block inside an aggregate function, such as `MAX`, which will return a row with a `null` and `COALESCE` can then handle the nulls to give you the desired value, when there are no rows.

```
SELECT
 COALESCE(
    MAX(
        CASE
            WHEN t.column1 =:column1  THEN 'XX'
            ELSE 'YY'
        END
    ),'YY')
FROM
    table1 t
WHERE
    t.column2 =:column2;
```

Comment: Thank You for your advise :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   case 
      when coalesce(table1.column1,'empty') = @column1
        then 'XX' 
      else 'YY' 
   end as SOMETHING
  from table1 
 where coalesce(table1.column2,'empty') = @column2
```

Coalesce is used to check if the value is null, and if it is, it changes to the value appointed right next to the column name. If you would provide your data, I could change sql query by your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN table1.column1= @column1  THEN 'XX' 
ELSE 'YY' END from table1 where case when table1.column2=@column2 then table1.column2 else @column2 end = @column2
```

Note: if there is more than one record in table1 then this query will return YY for all those rows

Answer (score -1):

Keeping it simple and easy for you.
First check if the data is available as per your `where` condition. If it is then do the rest of the query, if it isn't simply just return `YY`

for example:

```
   If exists(SELECT * from table1 where table1.column2=@column2)
    begin
        SELECT
        CASE WHEN table1.column1 = @column1  THEN 'XX' 
        ELSE 'YY' END AS [COLNAME]
        from table1 where table1.column2=@column2
    end
    else
    begin
       SELECT 'YY' as [COLNAME]
    End
```

to learn more about [EXISTS keyword click here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions012.htm)

Comment: This is not Oracle PL/SQL, which the OP says is what he is using.  Although SQL can use exists, you cannot use Exists in an IF statement.  Also your syntax for IF looks more like SQL Server.